# TextWatcher for multiple EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I want to be able to calculate something depending on the input in 2 of 3 `EditText`. For Example: I make an input in ET 1 and 2 -> i get a calculation in ET 3. ET 1 and 3 -> calculation in ET 2... and so on.

I get it to work with 2 `EditText` but with 3 I get an StackOverFlowError.

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1,
            int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1,
            int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.liter_input:
            try {
                if (amount_widget.getText().toString().equals(" ") == false
                        || literPrice_widget.getText().toString()
                                .equals(" ") == false
                        || price_widget.getText().toString().equals(" ") == false) {
                    double editTextCalc = Double.parseDouble(amount_widget
                            .getText().toString())
                            * Double.parseDouble(literPrice_widget
                                    .getText().toString());
                    editTextCalc = Math.round(editTextCalc * 100) / 100.0;
                    price_widget.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormat
                            .format(editTextCalc)));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            break;
        case R.id.literprice_input:
            try {
                if (amount_widget.getText().toString().equals(" ") == false
                        || literPrice_widget.getText().toString()
                                .equals(" ") == false
                        || price_widget.getText().toString().equals(" ") == false) {
                    double editTextCalc = Double.parseDouble(amount_widget
                            .getText().toString())
                            * Double.parseDouble(literPrice_widget
                                    .getText().toString());
                    editTextCalc = Math.round(editTextCalc * 100) / 100.0;
                    price_widget.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormat
                            .format(editTextCalc)));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            break;
        case R.id.price_input:
            try {
                if (amount_widget.getText().toString().equals(" ") == false
                        || literPrice_widget.getText().toString()
                                .equals(" ") == false
                        || price_widget.getText().toString().equals(" ") == false) {
                    double editTextCalc = Double.parseDouble(amount_widget
                            .getText().toString())
                            / Double.parseDouble(price_widget.getText()
                                    .toString());
                    editTextCalc = Math.round(editTextCalc * 100) / 100.0;
                    literPrice_widget.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormat
                            .format(editTextCalc)));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i just started to review my code again. Why hasn't anyone found an answer? It's really not that hard.

So i just just surrounded the `if-statements` in every try block with another `if-statement` which looks like this:

```
if(edittext.isFocused()){
   try-catch block
}
```

And now everything works just fine. There is no `StackOverflowException` anymore because the `textwatcher` only starts it's work where the `edittext` is focused. The text changes do not trigger an infinit loop anymore.

Comment: "Blog has been removed"

Answer (score 0):

You should check if change in an `EditText` happened because of changes made in other `EditText`. Create a `boolean` field in the class and initialize it with `false`:

```
private boolean mIsChanging = false;
```

In `afterTextChanged()` check if this field is `false` or exit otherwise:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (mIsChanging) {
        return;
    }

    mIsChanging = true;

    // Then do what you did previously...

    mIsChanging = false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, StackOverFlowError is gone but i get a very weird behavior. when entering something in my 2nd `EditText` there appears something very different than what i entered and when deleting my input those numbers get bigger and jump around.. Kinda hard to explain..

Comment: It's hard to recommend you something in this case. You can try to debug it. I'm sure you'll be able to find out where the problem is pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

With Editable is possible, you need to use hashCodeFunction

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (editText.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
        // some
    }
}
```